# openapi.json not found when hosting NetCore 3.1 Web Api on IIS

Tags: iis, .net-core-3.1, openapi-generator

I generated my server stub for ASP.NET Core 3.1 using the openapi generator with the following command:

`npx @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate -i myapi.json -g aspnetcore -o C:\myapi --additional-properties aspnetCoreVersion=3.1`

After opening that project in Visual Studio 2019 and running it I get the swagger page where I can try out the different endpoints. So far OK.

However: after publishing this on our IIS Server and visiting the proper URL that swagger page is loading with the error:

> Not found: /swagger/1.0.0/openapi.json

[Swagger error on IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmVPs.png)

The endpoint itself (GET request) can be reached.

The Swagger Endpoint code in startup.cs is the default code as it was generated by open-api generator:

```
app.UseSwagger(c =>
            {
                c.RouteTemplate = "swagger/{documentName}/openapi.json";
            })
            .UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                //TODO: Either use the SwaggerGen generated Swagger contract (generated from C# classes)
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/1.0.0/openapi.json", "Swagger WP RUH Delivery");

                //TODO: Or alternatively use the original Swagger contract that's included in the static files
                // c.SwaggerEndpoint("/openapi-original.json", "Swagger WP RUH Delivery Original");
            });
```

Why is this Swagger page working on my machine, but on IIS things go wrong?
I found some hints on changing the c.SwaggerEndpoint in startup.cs, but nothing helped.

Comment: How did you change c.SwaggerEndpoint in startup.cs? can you show me your startup.cs?

Comment: @samwu : I use the code as generated by the openapi generator: I updated my question with that code.

Comment: Try to  remove `/swagger/` from the URL path: `c.SwaggerEndpoint("1.0.0/openapi.json", "Swagger WP RUH Delivery")`;

Comment: Please mark my answer so that it can help others with similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove `/swagger/` from the URL path:

```
c.SwaggerEndpoint("1.0.0/openapi.json", "Swagger WP RUH Delivery")
```